# How to pass a column name into a custom function, which uses dplyr?

Tags: r, arguments, dplyr

I've written this function which just replaced each value in a data table's column with its substring:

```
substrColName <- function(df, colName, start) {
    df %>% mutate(colName = substr(colName, start=start, stop=nchar(colName)))
}
```

But every time I try running it I get the error:

```
Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Now I've done a lot of research on why it won't work but I can't figure it out. I've read on some stuff with standard evaluations and lazyeval but nothing I try seems to work. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the data with which you ran the function on?

Comment: See this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html to learn programming with dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @ycw, that was a nice read. Got it working now after working through the article. This was the solution at the end of the day:

```
substrColName <- function(df, colName, start) {
    colNameQuo <- enquo(colName)
    df %>% mutate(!!quo_name(colNameQuo) := substr(!!colNameQuo, start=start,stop=nchar(!!colNameQuo)))
}
```

[And this is ycw's comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616162/how-to-pass-a-column-name-into-a-custom-function-which-uses-dplyr?noredirect=1#comment80184273_46616162)